# Using @supports selector() despite Sass not supporting it

Tags: css, sass, media-queries, progressive-enhancement

I want to use the new [CSS feature queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports) by selector, like so:

```css
:root { --focus-shadow: 0 0 0 2.4px rgba(130, 138, 145, 0.5); }

/* Focus styles even for mouse selection in old browsers */
*:focus { outline: none; box-shadow: var(--focus-shadow); }

/* Newer browsers: Only add focus styles if e.g. navigating with the keyboard */
@supports selector(*:focus-visible) {
  *:focus { box-shadow: none; }
  *:focus-visible { box-shadow: var(--focus-shadow); }
```

```html
<a href="#">Focus me</a>
```

The above is valid CSS (although [poorly supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-focus-visible) as of June 2020), but Sass doesn't support it in either of its two implementations yet. [It's in the works](https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/issues/1023), but it looks like it'll take a while to implement it. Trying to compile the above through Sass throws an error (varies between Sass implementations; see [these](https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/issues/1023) [issues](https://github.com/sass/libsass/issues/3116) for details on the errors).

In the mean time, I want to trick Sass into compiling my support query as is, without trying to understand it. I tried a few things unsuccessfully. Using `unquote()`, this is the most promising attempt:

```
@mixin supports-selector( $selector ) {
   $query-str: #{ unquote( '@supports selector(' ) }#{ unquote( $selector ) }#{ ')' };

   #{ unquote( $query-str ) }#{ unquote( '{' ) }
      @content;
   #{ unquote( '}' ) }
}

:root { --focus-shadow: 0 0 0 2.4px rgba(130, 138, 145, 0.5); }

*:focus { outline: none; box-shadow: var(--focus-shadow); }

@include supports-selector( '*:focus-visible' ) {
    *:focus { box-shadow: none; }
    *:focus-visible { box-shadow: var(--focus-shadow); }
}
```

This *still* throws an error though, as Sass expects an arbitrary string to be a property followed by a colon:

> property "#{ unquote( $query-str ) }#{ unquote( '{' ) }" must be followed by a ':'

Not unquoting the `@supports` part results in error to the effect that `selector(whatever)` is not a valid @supports condition.

I don't know what else to try.

**How can I trick Sass into not compiling my mixin?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might work for you - by just escaping the characters, it will still compile to CSS.

The SASS/SCSS processor was getting hung up not on the `@supports`, but rather the `*:focus-visible`:

```
:root { --focus-shadow: 0 0 0 2.4px rgba(130, 138, 145, 0.5); }

/* Focus styles even for mouse selection in old browsers */
*:focus { outline: none; box-shadow: var(--focus-shadow); }

/* Newer browsers: Only add focus styles if e.g. navigating with the keyboard */
@supports #{'\(*:focus-visible)'} {
  *:focus { box-shadow: none; }
  *:focus-visible { box-shadow: var(--focus-shadow); }
}
```

Compiles to this:

```
:root {
  --focus-shadow: 0 0 0 2.4px rgba(130, 138, 145, 0.5);
}

/* Focus styles even for mouse selection in old browsers */
*:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: var(--focus-shadow);
}

/* Newer browsers: Only add focus styles if e.g. navigating with the keyboard */
@supports (*:focus-visible) {
  *:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
  }

  *:focus-visible {
    box-shadow: var(--focus-shadow);
  }
}
```

[SASSMEISTER Link](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/006e1d65762b13760fd9cb3f4a820927) to play with.

Edit: based on your comment, you can still add the `selector`:

```
@supports  #{'\selector(*:focus-visible)'}  {
  *:focus { box-shadow: none; }
  *:focus-visible { box-shadow: var(--focus-shadow); }
}
```

[Updated SASSMeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/82ef3c541842453048819e2d991ea9a5)

Comment: Sadly, I don't think this will do. It compiles because it interprets `*` as a property, and `focus-visible` as a value. It doesn't check whether the actual *selector* is supported. Here is a CodePen that demonstrates how that query doesn't fulfill its purpose: https://codepen.io/arianeb/pen/MWKOqZK :: **Note that for this to work, you need to use Chrome and activate the `#enable-experimental-web-platform-features` flag in chrome://flags.**

Comment: Updated my answer to include `selector`

Comment: You're a genius. Thank you very much.

Comment: Little note, if you don't need the `*` selector you can opt out of some of the syntax there: `@supports #{'selector(:focus-visible)'} {...}`